# PHP SQLite Screw-up

Tags: php, sqlite, installation

I tried installing SQLite for my system, it didn't work. Now any time I try to run PHP code though the terminal, this error is given:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite3.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20090626+lfs/sqlite3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

It's very annoying that I can't run PHP scripts.. Anyone know what I can do to fix this? I did a quick search on Google to fix the error and I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your PHP configuration includes a line similar to `extension=sqlite3.so`. This configuration is typically inside `/etc/php/` or `/etc/php5/`. Try `grep -r sqlite *` in that directory to find which config file mentions it, comment out that line using `;`, and restart your webserver.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this problem and [blogged about it](http://www.jorble.com/2012/01/php-startup-unable-to-load-dynamic-library-sqlite-so/). With Ubuntu, the problem didn't lie in the PHP.ini has most resources would lead you to believe. Inside the `/etc/php5/conf.d` directory was a bunch of *.ini* files for different extensions including `sqlite.ini` and `sqlite3.ini`.

If you look in the sqlite3.ini file, you'll see something like:

```
; configuration for php SQLite module
extension=sqlite3.so
```

All you have to do is comment that line so it looks like this:

```
; configuration for php SQLite module
; extension=sqlite3.so
```

This way it's not trying to look for the `sqlite3.so` file and will probably use your `sqlite.so` instead.